# Using @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator with "babel-preset-expo"

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, expo, create-react-native-app

The project was created with create-react-native-app.

When I use code like `const a = 2 ?? 3`, there will be an error complaining **"Cannot read property 'loose' of undefined"**.

I tried adding the [@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) plugin, but there's a build error.

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might be a problem with your babel version:

> Make sure that you've installed all the correct babel 7 dependencies,
>   e.g.:
>
> @babel/core instead of babel-core
>
> @babel/cli instead of babel-cli
>
> @babel/preset-env instead of babel-preset-env

https://www.menubar.io/cannot-read-property-loose-of-undefined/